# How to convert TextView value to Integer

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent

Good day programming warriors, please help me to this simple problem of mine, i'm new to android. How can I How to convert TextView value to Integer. please see my attached codes, thank you.

```
public class appleTrivia extends AppCompatActivity {

     public int total = 0;
     public int score = 40;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apple_trivia);


        TextView scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelScore);
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + getIntent().getExtras().getInt("points", 0));

        try {
            total = Integer.parseInt("score: " + scoreLabel);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe )
        {
        }
    }
        public void onClickProceed (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, cherry.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(appleTrivia.this, "Your score is:" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I need to convert scoreLabel value to integer so I can add it to another score, thank you.
PS.   Toast.makeText(appleTrivia.this, "Your score is:" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); give's me 0 score.

Comment: Look my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34481681/2649104). Same as your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to remove the `Score :` text using regex maybe :

```
String str = scoreLabel.getText().toString();      
str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", "");
```

Then parse it to integer :

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

**EDIT**

```
public class appleTrivia extends AppCompatActivity {

     public int total = 0;
     public int score = 40;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apple_trivia);


        TextView scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelScore);
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + getIntent().getExtras().getInt("points", 0));

        try {
            String str = scoreLabel.getText().toString();      
            str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", "");
            total = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe )
        {
        }
    }
        public void onClickProceed (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, cherry.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(appleTrivia.this, "Your score is:" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sir, thnx for the rapid replay, but it seems i didn't get your point, can you re code the source code that I post? i really don't have any idea where to insert the codes that you had gave. thnx ^_^

Comment: by the way sir, the code that you had gave me works, but i realize that the answer is a string value not integer value.

Comment: I need it to become integer so i can add all my score points.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Value in total and just display your result with a different string, if you want to add the int to another one you can use total and display it again.

```html
public class appleTrivia extends AppCompatActivity {

     public int total = 0;
     public int score = 40;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apple_trivia);


        TextView scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelScore);
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + getIntent().getExtras().getInt("points", 0));

        try {
        total = Integer.parseInt(scoreLabel.getText().ToString());
        String totalScore = "Score:" + Total; 
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe )
        {
        }
    }
        public void onClickProceed (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, cherry.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(appleTrivia.this, "Your score is:" + totalScore, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir this code gave me "Your score is: null" on toast message.

Comment: sorry i didn't get back to you any earlier. i don't know if you have fixed your issue. If not but apparently there is no function where you are adding the scores to total. and you have set the variable to be 0 therefore it shows null.