# How do I convert the value of a TextView to integer

Tags: android, textview, numeric-conversion

I am  designing a basic BMI calculator and I have the calculator working, but I need to convert the calculated answer from a TextView which is a double to an integer to enable me right statements with <> operators based on the calculated answer.
How do I convert the answer from the TextView to an integer?

```
    v.findViewById(R.id.bmi).setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bmi:

            try {


                EditText w = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.w);
                String value = w.getText().toString();
                EditText h = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.h);
                String value1 = h.getText().toString();

                TextView ans = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ans);
                Double l1 = Double.parseDouble(value);
                Double l2 = Double.parseDouble(value1);
                ans.setText(Double.toString(l1 / (l2 * l2)));                                     

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setNeutralButton("OK",null).setMessage("ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED TO COMPUTE YOUR BMI! ").show();
                break;
            }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: You are already doing something similar with doubles: `Double l1 = Double.parseDouble(value);`. If you want integers, do `int l1 = Integer.parseInt(value);`

Comment: I don't get it, your code hasn't got any problem. Why don't you just save your answer when you have calculated it?The question isn't clear.

Comment: the code runs fine, the issue here is I need to write some conditional statements based on the result using some operators , nd this will only work if I convert the computed answer from double to int

Comment: Alright, so why don't you just cast your answer from Double to Integer?

Comment: when I work with integer app crashes because the user enter number with decimals also

Comment: Tell me if I am getting you correct, you want to calculate answer in double, convert it into integer, do some operations on it?

Comment: exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, The conversion is **NOT** from `textview` to `int`. textView aint a datatype. If you want the result in int use `parseInt()` method. `int i = Integer.parseInt(value)`.

[EDIT]

Try this, this will work.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

try {
double d = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(et.getText()));
tv.setText(String.valueOf( (int) d));
}catch (NumberFormatException e){
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter valid number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have simplified it for your understanding. The code can still be optimized.

Comment: when user use number with decimal app crashes because integers are whole numbers

Comment: Can you add the crash report (log) to the answer.

Comment: 12-27 16:20:38.291 2012-2012/com.bosolutions.bmical E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "6.8"              the error comes from that line in the log when I use int

Comment: It will also take care if someone enters character input like "abc" instead of number

Comment: I just settled for the answer in double and use putextra to transfer the content of the textview to a textview in another activity . am satisfied with that .